# Web API Entity Framework Unit Of Work & Repository with Stored Procedures

Tags: .net, entity-framework, repository, unit-of-work, asp.net-web-api

I have a Generic Repository and UoW that I modeled after Honorable Mr. Dykstra's biblical account: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application.

```
namespace Bookstore.DAL
{
    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal BookstoreContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(BookstoreContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            query = includeProperties.Split(new[] {','},
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
                Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));

            return orderBy != null ? orderBy(query).ToList() : query.ToList();
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {

           dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(object id)
        {
            var entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
            Delete(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
        {
            if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
            }
            dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to do is override the insert method to use a store procedure that I have well defined in my context class.  I can easily bypass the UoW and build a controller that consumes the SP directly from context, but that would be less than optimal.

My question is:
**How do I override a method to use stored procedures that are defined in the context?**

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How do I override a method to use stored procedures that are defined in the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have to override the EF behavior at that level. The behavior of the EF repository is still "Add" to the collection of entities.

What you want to change is the "how" that entity is being added. [This article](http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/using-stored-procedures-for-insert-update-amp-delete-in-an-entity-data-model/) explains how to override the Insert behavior in EF

Happy coding!